# TreeView - Check if expanded and onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a `TreeView` with the Treeview component from Material UI: https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/

I have created the component below which fetches data when a node is expanded. Furthermore, the tree is build so each node that have children also is a tree, but I have two questions:

**Question 1:**
Right now the `fetchChildNodes` gets called each time a node is expanded. I want to change this so that i'm checking if the current node has been expanded before. If it has been expanded I don't want to call `fetchChildNodes`, but use the data fetched earlier. This is because I for a node can expand, close, and expand again, and the `fetchChildNodes` will in this process be called twice. How can I check this?

**Question 2:**
Is there some kind of `onClick` method that can provide the `nodeId` for the node clicked? The `expandingNodes` only provides `nodeId` for expandable nodes and not `leaf` nodes.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

export default function MyTreeItem(props) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          children: [
            {
              id: "2",
              name: "Calendar"
            },
            {
              id: "3",
              name: "Settings"
            },
            {
              id: "4",
              name: "Music"
            }
          ]
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  const handleChange = (event, nodes) => {
    const expandingNodes = nodes.filter(x => !expanded.includes(x));
    setExpanded(nodes);
    if (expandingNodes[0]) {
      const childId = expandingNodes[0];
      fetchChildNodes(childId).then(result =>
        setChildNodes(
          result.children.map(node => <MyTreeItem key={node.id} {...node} />)
        )
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
      onNodeToggle={handleChange}
    >
      {/*The node below should act as the root node for now */}
      <TreeItem nodeId={props.id} label={props.name}>
        {childNodes || [<div key="stub" />]}
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyTreeItem id="1" name="Applications" />, rootElement);
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19953#issuecomment-729001156

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering Question 2:

just add custom label object to TreeItem :

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

export default function MyTreeItem(props) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          children: [
            {
              id: "2",
              name: "Calendar"
            },
            {
              id: "3",
              name: "Settings"
            },
            {
              id: "4",
              name: "Music"
            }
          ]
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  const handleChange = (event, nodes) => {
    const expandingNodes = nodes.filter(x => !expanded.includes(x));
    setExpanded(nodes);
    if (expandingNodes[0]) {
      const childId = expandingNodes[0];
      fetchChildNodes(childId).then(result =>
        setChildNodes(
          result.children.map(node => (
            <MyTreeItem key={node.id} {...node}  />
          ))
        )
      );
    }
  };

  const renderLabel = item => (
    <span
      onClick={event => {
        console.log(item.id);
        //setActiveItemId(item.id);
        // if you want after click do expand/collapse comment this two line
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      {item.name}
    </span>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
      onNodeToggle={handleChange}
    >
      {/*The node below should act as the root node for now */}
      <TreeItem nodeId={props.id} label={renderLabel(props)}>
        {childNodes || [<div key="stub" />]}
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyTreeItem id="1" name="Applications" />,
  rootElement
);
```

[image: onclick screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: It's work for me see screenshot in my post, see TreeItem API doc

Answer (score 0):

**Question2 Answer:** You can use `onNodeSelect={action}`  on `TreeView` and action can be something like below

```
function action(event, nodeId) {
  console.log('nodeId: ', nodeId)
}
```

Comment: If I want to get parent node info as well like node position, node name. How can I achieve it. any idea

Comment: In my case I need to get parent info as well to fetch API call